# SQL UNION with conditions and recursive

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, union

i'm having problems with 2 query for my DB class.

I have one table "clients" with this columns:

```
name   | id     | date     | points | REFERRAL
---------------------------------------------
daniel | 123456 | 01-01-01 | 50     | 321321
jack   | 321321 | 01-01-01 | 30     | 555555
```

Note that daniel was refered by jack

1) With the ID of one person show all client referrals and referrals from them to a third reference level

First i think on something like this, just for a reference level of 2:

```
SELECT C1.name
FROM Clients C1, Clients C2
WHERE C1.REFERRAL= 21000301
      AND C1.id= C2.REFERRAL
```

This obviously not work for the AND.
Then I try UNION:

```
SELECT C1.id, C1.REFERRAL
FROM Clients C1
WHERE C1.REFERRAL= 21000301

UNION

SELECT C2.id, C2.REFERRAL
FROM Clients C2
WHERE C2.REFERRAL= C1.ID
```

But can't access C1 on the second SELECT

So, my question is there is a way to make conditions with the UNION.
If not, how can i solve this?

2) Show the name and the total number of referrals to the client with more direct and indirect referrals.

On this one I'm completely lost :D, May be it is recursive? Is there something like that in SQL?

Thanks in advance, and sorry my poor English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure it out :D

```
select c.name
from CLIENTS C
where c.REFERRAL=21000301 OR c.REFERRAL
   IN(SELECT c.id FROM CLIENTS C WHERE c.REFERRAL=21000301 OR c.REFERRAL
   IN(SELECT c.id FROM CLIENTS C WHERE c.REFERRAL=21000301 OR c.REFERRAL
   IN(SELECT c.id FROM CLIENTS C WHERE c.REFERRAL=21000301)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Im using: `c1.referral = 21000301` because i need the referrals of one person given the ID and that ID is on the table, just for testing.

I try this:

```
SELECT  C1.name
FROM    Clients C1
JOIN    Clients C2
ON      C1.id = C2.REFERRAL
JOIN    Clients C3
ON      C2.id = C3.REFERRAL
WHERE   c1.referral = 21000301
```

But it only shows one name 8 times.

And about the database i really don't know, my college is doing the hosting, I'm using Oracle SQL Developer if helps. Anyway I guess any code will help me.

Thanks!

Comment: Try to select c2.name and c3.name as well. PS instead of adding an answer to your own question, consider editing the question itself.

Comment: Thanks, about the DB we are using oracle 10g, hope you can help me with the second question.

Comment: better ask that in a new question tagged Oracle. I'm guessing it involves connect by, but the experts can tell you more :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason your first example doens't work is the `c1.referral = 21000301`: there is no row like that.  If you omit that, the query works:

```
SELECT  C1.name
FROM    Clients C1, Clients C2
WHERE   C1.id = C2.REFERRAL
```

Or rewritten more clearly as a join for two levels:

```
SELECT  C1.name
FROM    Clients C1
JOIN    Clients C2
ON      C1.id = C2.REFERRAL
JOIN    Clients C3
ON      C2.id = C3.REFERRAL
```

You'd only need a recursive query for an arbitrary level of referrals.  Recursive query syntax differs per database, so you'd have to tell us which database you are using.

Comment: Please see the next answer(code look awful here), i hope you can help me.